# How to write and publish an extension for Magento go?

Tags: magento, magento-go

I want to write an extension that is compatible with Magento Go ...

There is anything in particular to know about Magento Go on the dev side ?

Comment: Magento Go is based on Magento EE. Basic requirements for extension can be found in extension developer guide http://t.co/Ev7wxX8u But now new Go extensions are not accepted

Comment: thank you, I don't got what you mean 'now new Go extensions are not accepted'

Comment: You can write module for Go, but it should be approved by magento team  as "trusted extension". After this your module can be installed on Magento Go platform. But now adding new trusted extensions is suspended.

Answer (score 0):

Your module should be reviewed by Magento team. See more here - [Trusted Magento Extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/trusted_extension/).

Comment: link returns now a 404 :(

Comment: Oops, seems like Magento removed that page :(

Comment: yeah, it's like they don't want any magento go extensions anymore :(